# How Do I Define A Private Repo That Works On CI And Developer PCs?

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, artifactory, credentials, bamboo

The definition of my private Artifactory repo in my `build.gradle` currently looks like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory.example.com/maven-repo"
        credentials {
            username "${repo-username}"
            password ${repo-password}"
        }
    }
}
```

This works on developer PCs by having values in the `GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties`.

It works on Bamboo by passing in Bamboo Variables (stored in the build plan) on the command line. e.g.

```
./gradlew -Prepo-username=$bamboo_repo_user -Prepo-password=$bamboo_repo_pass
```

Now we are moving to Azure DevOps and we are supposed to use Service Credentials instead of usernames and passwords.

How do we define the repos in the `build.gradle` so that it works with both Azure DevOps Service Credential and also developer PCs at the same time?